# How to convert a list of duplicate tuples to a list of unique tuples?

Tags: java, arrays, unique

I am working on a piece of code that contains a list of tuples with duplicates and I want to remove the duplicates from this list WITHOUT using HASHSET or SET. I am only allowed to use Arrays, ArrayList, and Iterator.

The following code is going to overflow/infinite loop. I understand why is it going to infinite loop cycles because I am adding the element and size also increases.

Tuple class:

```
public class Tuple {
    private int key;
    private String value;

    public Tuple(int keyP, String valueP) {
        key = keyP;
        value = valueP;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }  

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean equals(Tuple t) {
        if (this.key == t.getKey() && this.value.equals(t.getValue())) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}

ArrayList < Tuple > union= new ArrayList<Tuple>();
ArrayList < Tuple > unique= new ArrayList<Tuple>();

Union: [Tuple < 15, a >, Tuple < 17, a >, Tuple < 15, a >, Tuple<79, b>] 

unique.add(union.get(0));

for (int k = 1; k < union.size(); k++) {
    Tuple test= union.get(k);
    for (int j= 0; j < unique.size();j++) {
        if (!test.equals(unique.get(j))) {
            System.out.println(union.get(k));
            unique.add(union.get(k));
        }
    }
}
```

Unique should be

```
[Tuple< 15, a >, Tuple< 17, a >, Tuple< 79, b >]
```

I am totally stuck for more than a day. Please help me out.

Comment: Much better. The line `Union : [Tuple< 15, a >, Tuple< 17, a >, Tuple< 15, a >, Tuple< 79, b >] Union : [Tuple< 15, a >, Tuple< 17, a >, Tuple< 15, a >, Tuple< 79, b >] ` doesn't compile.

Comment: I actually figured it out, so I am just going to post the answer.

Comment: Btw.: In the process of generating an [mcve] to publish my question on SE, I usually solve 90% of my problems myself. It's the sorting of ideas, getting to the core, and talking to an imaginary audience, which leads to this. It's the non-obvious benefit of mcves. The more obvious one is, that 100 readers, each setting up the example instead of one, is not economic.

Comment: Hint: you should use the @Override annotation when overriding methods, for example on your equals method. That would have resulted in an compiler error - telling you that the signature should be `equals(Object)` - and not `equals(Tupel)`. Never override "standard" methods like this!

Answer (score 0):

Override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` method on key, value variables of Tuple. Then you can use `contains()` method of List directly instead of looping through `unique` List each time.

File: Tuple.java

```
public class Tuple {
    private int key;
    private String value;

    public Tuple(int keyP, String valueP) {
        key = keyP;
        value = valueP;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tuple [key=" + key + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + key;
        result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Tuple other = (Tuple) obj;
        if (key != other.key)
            return false;
        if (value == null) {
            if (other.value != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

File: TupleMain.java

```
public class TupleMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Tuple> union = Arrays.asList(new Tuple(15, "a"), new Tuple(17, "a"), new Tuple(15, "a"),
                new Tuple(79, "b"));
        List<Tuple> unique = new ArrayList<Tuple>();

        unique.add(union.get(0));
        for (int k = 1; k < union.size(); k++) {
            Tuple test = union.get(k);
            if (!unique.contains(test)) {
                unique.add(test);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(unique);

        // The Java 8 way
        union.stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better options but using your requirements you can add a flag to your loop...

```
    ArrayList<Tuple> union= new ArrayList<Tuple>();
    ArrayList<Tuple> unique= new ArrayList<Tuple>();

    union.add(new Tuple(15, "a"));
    union.add(new Tuple(17, "a"));
    union.add(new Tuple(15, "a"));
    union.add(new Tuple(79, "b"));

    unique.add(union.get(0));

    for(int k=1;k<union.size();k++) {

        Tuple test=union.get(k);
        Boolean exists = false;
        for(int j=0;j<unique.size();j++) {

            if(test.equals(unique.get(j))) {
                exists = true; 
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!exists) {
            System.out.println(union.get(k));
            unique.add(union.get(k)); 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Without data, we can confess the compiler to act on an empty List of Tuples:

```
-> union.stream().distinct()
|  Expression value is: java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1@4493d195
|    assigned to temporary variable $58 of type Stream<Tuple>
```